# mqtt output in node red disconnected to watson iot service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, node-red, watson-iot

I have accidentally deleted Watson IoT service on my space. I have created a recent one and tried to configure a mqtt subscriber via node-red to send data to the new service. 
It always shows disconnected to the service even though I did all the configuration requirements. ( Server , topic , token authentification .. ).

PS: I am using port 1883 and I have changed the service security to TLS optional.

What should I look up for ? Do I have to change other changed settings ?

[image]

Comment: What did you set the client id to? Watson IoT requires client id's to match a specific format to identify the type of device.

Comment: d:<orgid>:<device_id>

Comment: If you can provide you 6 character org ID we can check the logs for errors.

Comment: Actually, I resolved the problem I had to add <device type> before <device id>. Thank you.